# Subscriber and Publisher node at once in cpp

Tags: ros, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i need some an example how to wrtie a node, wich is subscribing and publishing at the same time.
I want to publish a message when i got i message, beacuse of that i try to publish in the Callback function, but it doesn't work.

My code is following:

```
void pointCallback(const nxt_msgs::Range  &msg)
{
         sensor_msgs::LaserScan pub;
         ros::NodeHandle r;
         ros::Publisher laser_scan_pub = r.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("laser_scan", 50);
         laser_scan_pub.publish(pub);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

 ros::init(argc, argv, "range_to_laser");
 ros::NodeHandle n;
 ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("point_cloud", 50, pointCallback);
 ros::spin();

 return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9339/subscriber-and-publisher-node-at-once-in-cpp/) by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-08**:
from ros-users mail

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-02**:
@tfoote could you solve this after all? Im trying to do the same and im having trouble accomplishing it, any help would be great , thanks

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-02**:
Please see accepted answer from tfoote below. It perfectly describes why the above code does not work and also how it should be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wouldn't create the Publisher in the callback.
Usually I have a class where I create the publisher in
the constructor and store it in a member variable.
Publishing can then be done from a callback method,
that uses the publisher member to call .publish().

You could also use a global variable to store the publisher
object if you do not want classes. Or you bind the publisher
boost::bind to the callback.

See
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers
for more info.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-02**:
@tfoote after understanding the answer I still cant manage to make it work, could you post the code that finally worked, i would really appreciate it ? Thanks

**Comment by [skyhawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/17746/skyhawk/) on 2014-05-06**:
Can you give me a specific solution to this problem, like a sample code will be helpful. Thank you.

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-08-08**:
I'm also trying to do something like this, and some sample code would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Better solution:
ros::Publisher //declare this globally

laser_scan_pub.publish(pub); //put this in same function

//change the following to main function
ros::NodeHandle r;
laser_scan_pub = r.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("laser_scan", 50);

---

Originally posted by [new_forROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22444/new_forros/) with karma: 31 on 2015-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-27**:
This is part of @tfoote's solution. This was the second of his three proposed solutions. Also, using globals is usually *not* the best solution and works "good enough" if your node is short. Otherwise, it can become quite confusing.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-08-09**:
Quality lies in the eye of the observer ....